# Logs for list of pods

Tags: openshift

I want to obtain the log for all the pods that I currently have.

If I do:

```
oc logs $(oc get pods -o custom-columns=POD:.metadata.name --no-headers)
```

I get:

```
error: expected 'logs [-f] [-p] (POD | TYPE/NAME) [-c CONTAINER]'.
POD or TYPE/NAME is a required argument for the logs command
```

Nevertheless, if I just run `oc get pods -o custom-columns=POD:.metadata.name --no-headers` I get a correct list with just the names of the pods.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to loop over the returned Pod names:

```
for p in $(oc get pods -o custom-columns=POD:.metadata.name --no-headers); do
  oc logs $p
done
```

Note that when you want to get the logs for all Pods of a single DeploymentConfig you can directly use that as an argument for `oc logs`:

```
oc logs dc/myapplication
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to do it without the for loop? For the `describe` I can pass the list directly